# Why does not `\cref` command yield proper output when certain equation is removed from its range?

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, cleveref

It is odd to see that `\cref` does not work when Eq. (2) is removed from its range. When I remove another equation, it just works perfectly. Reordering the equations labels does not seem to work.

Referring to all equations individually by using `,,` among labels works. However, I want the text to be as compact as possible, so using `,,` to separate labels and explicitly refer to each equation is not desired.

[image]

My source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{Eq. (#1)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Eqs. (#1) to (#2)}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{Eqs. (#1)}{ and (#1)}{, (#1)}{ and (#1)}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Eqs. (#1) to (#2)}{}{}{}


\begin{document}


\begin{align}
    y &= x_{1} + x_{2}
    \label{eq:1}
    \\
    y &= a \thinspace x + b
    \label{eq:2}
    \\
    e &= m \thinspace c^{2}
    \label{eq:3}
    \\
    y^{2} + x^{2} &= r^{2} 
    \label{eq:4}
    \\
    \int\limits_{0}^{\inf} e^{-x^{2}} &= \sqrt{\pi}
    \label{eq:5}
\end{align}


\rule{0pt}{1\normalbaselineskip}

Referring to the whole range of equation works

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}

\rule{0pt}{1\normalbaselineskip}

Referring to all equations as a range except \cref{eq:2} does not work

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}

\rule{0pt}{1\normalbaselineskip}

Referring to all equations individually works 

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,,eq:3,,eq:4,,eq:5}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: you should have more arguments than those in your definitions. I don't see why that would have the effect shown, though. Does it work with a regular class?

Comment: Oh, you're just throwing the information away. Don't do that! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your definition just throws everything but a single reference or reference range away, so if there is a gap after the first reference, nothing else is typeset because that's what you've told `cleveref` to do in that case.

Your first three custom formats work OK, although they will fail if you use `hyperref`. However, the fourth, `\crefrangemultiformat{}{}{}{}{}` throws away not only the anchoring information for links, but all cross-reference information apart from the first.

Changing that definition to

```
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{#3Eqs. ((#1))#4 to #5((#2))#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
```

produces what I assume is the expected result.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{#2Eq. (#1)#3}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{#3Eqs. (#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{#2Eqs. (#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{#3Eqs. ((#1))#4 to #5((#2))#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
    y &= x_{1} + x_{2}
    \label{eq:1}
    \\
    y &= a \thinspace x + b
    \label{eq:2}
    \\
    e &= m \thinspace c^{2}
    \label{eq:3}
    \\
    y^{2} + x^{2} &= r^{2} 
    \label{eq:4}
    \\
    \int\limits_{0}^{\inf} e^{-x^{2}} &= \sqrt{\pi}
    \label{eq:5}
\end{align}



Referring to the whole range of equation works.

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,eq:2,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}.
\bigskip

Referring to all equations as a range except \cref{eq:2} works fine when the definition doesn't throw the information away.

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,eq:3,eq:4,eq:5}.

\bigskip

Referring to all equations individually works.

Some remarks on \cref{eq:1,,eq:3,,eq:4,,eq:5}.



\end{document}
```

[image: all present and correct]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the need for #3 to #6 entries? Also, why did you order them in this particular way?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh They are necessary in case you use `hyperref`. The ordering is just based on their meaning e.g. with one reference `#2#1#3` gives the target, with more than one `#1` and `#2` are the references and the anchors are `#3`, `#4`, `#5` and `#6`. See the manual for details. I just copied from my `cleveref.cfg` (which I wrote reading the manual).